# Why can't different messages result in the same ciphertext when encrypted with RSA?

Tags: rsa

In the encryption step of the RSA encryption to get the cypher text $C$

$C \equiv M^e \pmod n$

I am struggling to understand how we know that there only exists one $M$ that maps to a certain $C$?

Does there not exist an $M$ and an $N$ such that $M^e \equiv N^e \pmod n$? How do we know this?

Comment: Related [RSA_(cryptosystem) - Proofs_of_correctness (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Proofs_of_correctness)

Answer (score 2):

The property that you are talking about is the injectivity. I think this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632476/how-to-make-rsa-function-injective) will maybe help you.